# How to identify the endianness of given hex string?

Tags: x86, endianness

For example :

The Hex string is:- **70 6f 77 65 72 73 68 65 6c 6c**

The ASCII for above string is : **powershell**

I want to know how to identify the above string is in little endian or big endian.

Suppose if I change byte order to other endian **6f 70 65 77 73 72 65 68 6c 6c** 
then the ascii is **“opwesrehll”**.

If i am changing the byte order then value is changing. I think something went wrong in conversion.

How to convert to other endian format with out altering the main value **"powershell"** ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Endianness is typically not a concept applied to (ASCII) strings, as there's one byte per character, and it would be weird for the entire string to be stored in reverse order in memory.

Comment: Bytes don't have endianness.

Comment: Further, you can detect the endianness of a system but not of data. The endianness of data is what the writer used; Ask. So, I ask you: when you write 70, do you mean that the value is 7 *16 + 0 * 1? High nibble first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Bytes don't have endianness."* – @MichaelPetch

Is correct because your ASCII is one byte per letter. So just build-up your word from reading each byte for one letter at a time.

> *"Suppose if I change byte order to other endian `6f 70 65 77 73 72 65 68 6c 6c` 
> then the ascii is “opwesrehll”.*

That happens if you flip 2 bytes a time, but this is ASCII (**alphabet characters**)... 
You are supposed read **one byte for each letter** and no flips/endianness are involved. Flips only count for **numerical values** stored within `Short` (2 bytes) or `Integer` / `Float` (4 bytes) even per `Long`/ `Double` (8 bytes) etc.

> *"I want to know how to identify the above string is in little endian or big endian."*

Side Note: **UTF-16** (not ASCII) can sometimes use more than 1 byte for alphabetic characters (especially with foreign alphabets like Japanese Russian Arabic etc). For such cases the text would begin with a two-byte flag called BOM (byte-order mark) to say what endian the bytes are. Check `bytes[0]` and if this first byte `[0]` gives 255 as value (0xFF) and then check also `bytes[1]` if this next following byte gives 254 (0xFE), your UTF text is little endian. For big endian you expect 0xFE followed by 0xFF. Stil it all works because your check **one byte at a time**...

Comment: A BOM does not have this purpose with UTF-8. It is only meant as a way of communicating the encoding. (Some argue for it; some against.) UTF-8 bytes (code units) for a codepoint are still a specific sequence of bytes. Endianness of words is not relevant.